# what is the easiest web scraping tool that handles javascripts

Tags: javascript, python

I would like to make a web scraping application that is able to log in to a website (I was able to do this with twill (python)), and also to be able to execute JavaScript which trigger access to other pages.

I would definitely prefer to use something in python, but I am ready to try something new. I have installed mechanize, watir, Hojocki, etc. but not sure if this really helps.

Comment: https://github.com/makinacorpus/spynner

Comment: "easiest" is subjective. There are several possible tools listed in the question itself.

Comment: you are right: it is subjective. To clarify I was not able to execute the javascript with twill/python. So I'm looking either for a library in python that could do that, or try another tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are a few modules (such as [Ghost](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/)), but I have used [Selenium](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PythonBindings)/WebDriver for things like this. It is ostensibly a testing framework, but it provides you with a lot of methods to allow you to interact with the page just as if you had loaded it as a normal user. You also have the benefit of running it so that a browser actually opens and you can watch the code execute (makes debugging easier), or in a 'headless' mode where the code just executes (there are other sites/SO answers with much better explanations than I can give :) ).

That being said, Ghost looks great as well, so try them both and hopefully one will get you what you need!

Also, see [Javascript (and HTML rendering) engine without a GUI for automation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716230/javascript-and-html-rendering-engine-without-a-gui-for-automation) for a similar question that may have some additional answers.

Comment: I have tried Selenium and ran immediately in one issue: I cannot fill in the password without getting a ElementNotVisibleException. If I understand it, there is no workaround.

Comment: One thing you may want to try is using the wait method that is provided (can get syntax later if you'd like). Basically you need to wait for the page to load before accessing its elements. An additional benefit is that you can build specialized profiles that can carry authentication credentials (in some cases).

Comment: A combination of Selenium and BeautifulSoup worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: No prob man, glad to hear it!

Comment: One big issue with Ghost.py I just discovered: it cannot be used from the command line...

Comment: @RockridgeKid Ah, that is good to know. Did Selenium get the job done overall?

Comment: Selenium was working fine. However I was looking for a headless solution afterwards. The one that works for me now is [spynner](https://github.com/makinacorpus/spynner).

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).

It's a full Webkit browser, but headless and scriptable.

It's ideal for this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I instead went for Selenium and BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Octoparse, a free web scraper](http://www.octoparse.com/) for Windows.
It's not programmble but it's very easy to use. But there's no Mac version.So...
JavaScript can be handled by Octoparse btw.